# Delete from the database the registry selected on the listview (Using Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview, orm

Visual Studio Community 2015 + SQLite + Entity Framework (WPF Application)

Database with fields: Id y ShipType

Class por database mapping:

```
namespace ImperialFleet
{
    public class ShipTypeClass
    {
        public ShipTypeClass(string id, string type)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.ShipType = type;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ShipType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ListView code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo nave" Width="Auto" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShipType}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code to Fill the Listview:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
    {
        listView.ItemsSource = db.ShipsType.ToList();
    }

}
```

Then I have a button to delete the registry selected by the user on the ListView

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here I want to delete the registry

}
```

I think it must be something like

```
using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
    {
        db.ShipsType.Remove(IDdelItemSelectedOnTheListView);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**But I don't know how to catch the Id number from the ListView and point that Id to the object to delete**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have highlighted the item you want to select in your listview, you can then proceed to find it like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem as ShipTypeClass;

    // Here's your ID, but you won't need it to remove the row in your database.
    var selectedShipID = selectedItem.Id;

    using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
    {
        db.ShipsType.Attach(selectedItem);
        db.ShipsType.Remove(selectedItem);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. I get redline under both(selectedItem);

(local variable) ShypTypeClass selectedItem
Argument1: cannot convert from 'ImperialFleetShipTypeClass' to 'ImperialFleet.ShipsType'

Comment: 'db.ShipsType' is 'DbSet' is of which type? Based on your provided example, one would assume `db.ShipsType` is `DbSet<ShipTypeClass>`.

Comment: If I type db.ShypsType the tip say "Sytem.Data.Entity.DdSet<ShypsType> ImperialFleetDBEntities.ShipsType{ get; set;}

Comment: If I only run:

`var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem as ShipTypeClass;`
`var selectedShipID = selectedItem.Id;`
`MessageBox.Show("ID " + selectedShipID);`

I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ImperialFleet.exe

So I think the first assignation is not working, or something with the model

Comment: Solved now! 

I replaced:
`var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem as ShipTypeClass` with `var selectedItem = (ShipsType)listView.SelectedItems[0];`
The rest if fine. Thanks!

Comment: The general idea is along that line, but if you include your DbContext class, it would make your questions clearer. Glad you found your way out, haha.

Comment: Sorry IvanJazz I was not sure about what is "DbContext class" . Just learning